# How to calculate compounding interest in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a small question regarding compounding calculations,
So, the scenario is that we are holding loans and loan payments. The interest for the loan is calculated monthly for the remaining loan amount (prev amount – payments);
Example:
[image]

The issue I’m facing is getting the previous row’s ‘New Loan Amount’ to be used as the new ‘Loan Amount’. Any feedback for this is appreciated.

Comment: You should look at `lag` function

Comment: I did try lag function. It seems to be working if the two columns are not depending on each other. In my case, the new loan amount(from the previous row) is needed to calculate the new loan amount

Comment: I think you need to use **`pandas udaf`** if every row depends on calculation of last row. available from **`spark2.3+`**